# What is the better solution for this Factory Method problem

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

Consider the following inheritance hierarchy

```
public interface SupperConf{}//empty

class ConfigurationA implements SupperConf {
   public void setProA(String proA){}
}

class ConfigurationB implements SupperConf {
   public void setProB(String proB){}
}

class ConfigurationC implements SupperConf {
   public void setProC(String proB){}
}
```

I have the following factory method

```
public final class ConfigurationManager{

   public static SupperConf getConfiguration(String confType){
      SupperConf conf = null;
      switch (confType)) {
        case "confA":
             configuration = new ConfigurationA();
        break;
        case "confB":
             configuration = new ConfigurationB();
        break;
        case "confC":
             configuration = new ConfigurationC();
        break;
       }
      return configuration;

    }

  }


public class app{
    public static void main(String agrs[]){
        // this doesn't compile
        ConfigurationA confA = ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration("confA");
        confA.setProA("proA");
    }
}
```

What changes do I have to make so that `getConfiguration` actually returns a `ConfigurationA` that I can then call `setProA` on?

I know I can use a cast

```
ConfigurationA confA = (ConfigurationA)ConfigurationManager.getConfiguration("confA");
```

But I'd like a cleaner solution if an appropriate pattern exists.

Comment: What is the variable `configuration` in the method `getConfiguration(String)`? Shouldn't you set and return the variable `conf`, which you initialize with `null` the line before the `switch`?

Comment: You can't. The implementing classes have different methods and no common methods.

Answer (score 0):

this should compile:

```java
public class ConfigManager {
    public static  <T extends SuperConf> T getConfiguration(Class<T> typeClass, String confType){
        SuperConf conf = null;
        switch (confType) {
            case "confA":
                conf = new ConfigA();
                break;
            case "confB":
                conf = new ConfigB();
                break;
        }
        return (T) conf;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigA config = ConfigManager.getConfiguration(ConfigA.class, "configA");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@sudipn's answer is pretty close however you don't even need to pass the class as an argument since you are not using the passed in class to create an instance.

```
    public static <T extends SupperConf> T getConfiguration(String confType){
        SupperConf configuration = null;
        switch (confType) {
            case "confA":
                configuration = new ConfigurationA();
                break;
            case "confB":
                configuration = new ConfigurationB();
                break;
            case "confC":
                configuration = new ConfigurationC();
                break;
        }
        return (T) configuration;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First , as commented by user - f1sh, your case is not standard factory method since your super interface `SupperConf` doesn't define common behavior to be implemented by all sub classes. So in standard factory method case, a cast is not needed since public methods are common among child classes & super interface.

So broader question in your case is - if your child classes doesn't have common behavior to super class & among themselves , why are you trying to write a standard factory method as your solution ? Wouldn't a simple `new` be more appropriate? To me, it looks you are unnecessarily trying to fit in Factory Method Design pattern in your case & removing that factory logic would result in more cleaner solution.

Having said that, you should try to use Enums instead of String to know the type in factory - that is more cleaner since clients will call your factory by passing enums & not by String ( which is error prone ) ,

```
public enum ConfType {

    CONFA, CONFB, CONFC;

}
```

& Lastly, I don't agree with solutions of armandino or sudipn to try to fit in cast in factory method since cast information is a client side responsibility & client is free to do cast or no cast ( as the case may be ) but not returning super interface seems a clear violation of programming to an interface principle.

Your below questions makes sense only if you clarify more about relations between `SupperConf` & child classes . `SupperConf` being empty gives an impression that relationship is being enforced upon when there is no natural relationship.

> But I'd like a cleaner solution if an appropriate pattern exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding the aim of the code you posted, but the point is: why do you need to have three different classes with three different methods implementing an empty interface that you are not using? 
I think that your example does not need a pattern at all (I admit that I am not a fan of patterns, especially when they're not really needed, cause they often make your software complex, moving your attention from core logic to design, losing focus on solving the original problem)... this way the complexity increases, and you don't want/need it.

I would rather rethink the solution as simple as possible, just using a simple interface implementation without any factory at all:

in my opinion, a simple (but effective) solution could be the following:

```
public interface ConfigurationInterface {
    public void setProperty();
}
```

Now let's define custom implementors

```
class ConfigurationA implements ConfigurationInterface {
    public void setProperty() {
        // Do stuff to set a property with A implementation
    }
}

class ConfigurationB implements ConfigurationInterface {
    public void setProperty() {
        // Do stuff to set a property with B implementation
    }
}

class ConfigurationC implements ConfigurationInterface {
    public void setProperty() {
        // Do stuff to set a property with C implementation
    }
}
```

So, just use the interface instead of objects:

```
public class app{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        // simple, understandable, and maintainable.
        ConfigurationInterface configurationA = new ConfigurationA();
        configurationA.setProperty("I am an example property");
    }
}
```

If you need to know the type of implementors, just use instanceof, but if your application is well designed, this can relate only to few cases (or none at all), using the interface to hide different implementations' complexity to interface user :)

If this is not enough, and you really need a factory to have a dynamic variable-based instantiation, you can use a simple static method that takes an Enum (as said by User - f1sh) and returns an instance of the right Object ;)